# Join list of string to comma separated and enclosed in single quotes

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, string-formatting

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add("test's");
test.Add("test");
test.Add("test's more");
string s = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", test));
```

now the s is `'test's','test','test's more'`
but I need to replace the inner quotes with 2 single quotes

like this: `'test''s','test','test''s more'`

update: I got it to work as below, but I would prefer a cleaner way if possible.

```
string s = string.Format("`{0}`", string.Join("`,`", test)).Replace("'", "''").Replace("`", "'");
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>(); 
test.Add("test's"); 
test.Add("test"); 
test.Add("test's more");
string s = string.Join("','", test.Select(i => i.Replace("'", "''")));
```

And if you're really looking to enclose the whole thing in single quotes:

```
string s = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", test.Select(i => i.Replace("'", "''"))));
```

Answer (score 36):

This may be easier than using `string.replace`

```
string s = "'" + String.Join("','", test) + "'";
```

Comment: But this doesn't escape the single quotes.  Solution by Jay Riggs is correct for the original poster's situation.

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = string.Join(",", itemsList.Select(i => $"'{i}'"));
```

Using string interpolation. `String.Replace` is not required here.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string s = string.Join(",", test.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x.Replace("'", "''"))));
```

By the way, there's no apostrophe in "tests" - apostrophes [aren't used for plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_case).

Comment: :) You are right. I made up some test list, I didn't really mean to say test's. Just some data with apostrophe is all I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't to everyone's taste, but I like to create helper extensions for these kinds of tasks, and put them into a "utility" namespace:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
   public static void AddDoubleQuoted(this List<string> list, string input)
   {
     input = input.Replace("'", "''");
     list.Add(input);
   }
}

List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.AddDoubleQuoted("test's");
test.AddDoubleQuoted("test");
test.AddDoubleQuoted("test's more");
string s = string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", test));
```

Comment: this one is cool, I prefer the above one is because I need it in just one place to use it. However I just learned how to create extensions. Thanks.

Comment: @gangt No problem! The first time I learned extensions I thought it was pretty awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(",", listofstring.Select(x=> $"'{x}'"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I like a version without Replace:

```
using System.Linq;
(...)
string s = String.Join(", ", from l in MyList select String.Format("'{0}'", l));
```